# What is the right way to include Hadoop classes in a project

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jar

I am trying to import a Hadoop class to use in my project.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
```

I would normally expect to go out into the world and try to find a Hadoop JAR file to include, put it in a libs folder in eclipse, then use the classes. Having done that and not found what I expected, I ask: what is the right way to include Hadoop classes in my own Java class so that I can use them in eclipse?

I found Hadoop documentation frustrating because it has an incredibly short shelf life. Advice from six months ago apparently is totally worthless.

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using (or what version does the cluster you are utilizing use?). Are you using a build tool such as Ant / Maven?

Comment: This is all new work so I am using the current version 1.1.1. We use ant, not mvn. I finally found a third-party website where I could download a hadoop-core.jar, which is swell and pretty much solves my problem, but leaves me wondering how everyone else does it using only first-party resources?

Comment: Do you use ivy for dependency management in Ant? I imagine most people use some dependency management enabled build tool such as Ant with Ivy, or maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using maven and the m2e plugin, a hadoop project is as simple as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>csw.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-sandbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And maven will handle downloading the jar and dependencies for you, the Eclipse maven plugin will manage the build path for you.

I'm sure there's a Eclipse ivy plugin too, that will do the same thing for Ant

Comment: This is what I meant when I said the documentation was frustrating. Are you saying that m2e is a good way to get Hadoop today, in December 2012? Because it was "a giant mess" whenever the comment was put at the bottom of this page, leading me to avoid going down the m2e path: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment

Comment: I think that page is geared towards people editing the hadoop source and contributing the changes back. Absolutely m2e is a good way to go, i've been using it since 2009, but if you're already using Ant then look into Ivy (it uses the same public maven repositories)

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I will continue to wish for more clear help files and for Apache to release hadoop jar files.